# what is the volume of a tilted glass

Tags: integration, geometry, solution-verification, volume

I was wondering about the volume of a tilted glass (60$^o$).
Not sure, but my attempt:

$$y=\sqrt{x}, \space 0<x<9$$

$$x=y^2,\space 0<y<3$$

$$A(y)=\pi x^2=\pi y^4$$

$$V(y)=\int_0^3 \pi y^4\,dy$$

$$V=\frac{243 \pi}{5}$$

$$V(\text{adjusted})=\sin(60^o)*V=\frac{243\sqrt{3 \pi}}{10}$$

Some help to get?

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: $\pi x^2=\pi y^4$ is the area of a cross-section perpendicular to the $x$-axis, so you have to integrate it for $x$ over $[0,9]$, not for $y$ over $[0,3]$. (And then we get to $V$(adjusted), which surely can't be right.)

Comment: Apparently, this was asked on a Danish forum: https://www.studieportalen.dk/forums/thread.aspx?id=1966469

Answer (score 1):

We can find the volume without computing integrals, using a theorem by Archimedes of Syracuse:

> The volume of a segment of a paraboloid of revolution is $3/2$ the
> volume of the cone which has the same base and whose vertex lies on
> the paraboloid, forming with
> the center of the base a line parallel to its axis.

Note that the plane tangent to the paraboloid at the vertex of the cone is parallel the base. Hence that cone could also be described as the cone of maximal volume inscribed into the paraboloid.

Below you can see a section of the paraboloid, perpendicular to the surface of the water (line $AB$). The base of the segment is an ellipse, having $AB$ as major axis and its midpoint $M$ as center. The cone described in the above theorem has vertex $V$, with $VM$ parallel to the axis of the paraboloid.

It is easy to find the coordinates of those points:
$$
A=(9,3);\quad
B=\left(\frac{28}{3}-2 \sqrt{3},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}-3\right);\quad
M=\left(\frac{55}{6}-\sqrt{3},\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}\right);\quad
V=\left(\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}\right).
$$
The semi-major axis of the base is then
$$
a={1\over2}AB=2 \sqrt{3}-\frac{1}{3},
$$
while the semi-major axis is the distance of $M$ from the paraboloid, along a direction perpendicular to plane $ABV$:
$$
b=\sqrt{x_M-y_M^2}=3-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}.
$$
Finally, we can compute the height $h$ of the cone:
$$
h=VH=VM\sin60°=\frac{109}{8 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{3}{2}.
$$
The volume of the segment of paraboloid is thus:
$$
{3\over2}\cdot{1\over3}\cdot\pi ab\cdot h =
\frac{1}{288} \left(12313-2616 \sqrt{3}\right) \pi
\approx 84.887962.
$$

[image]

Comment: What is the final value?

Comment: @Jeremy I added the approximate value, if that is what you need.

Comment: With integration I calculated 82.974.

Comment: Who created this theorem?

Comment: By the way: with the same method it is easy to compute the volume of the full glass, which is ${81\over2}\pi$.

Comment: Nine squared over two multiplied by pi.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if we reposition our axis to be parallel and perpendicular to the water level this is the equaivalent of performing the following:
$$\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(60)&-\sin(60)\\\sin(60)&\cos(60)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$$
so you can substituted these into the equation to get new formulas for the lines and then work out from there. Alternatively you could imagine the current axis at normal positions and notice the water is at a 60 degree angle and form new limits to the integral for this

Answer (score -1):

The line of the $60$ degree angle can be described by $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}y + 9 - \sqrt{3}$

The area enclosed by the curve and the line can be calculated with an integral.

$\int{}{}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}y + 9 - \sqrt{3}} - y^2$

You need to find the limits of integration. For the right side, it will be 3 since the limit of the glass is 9. For the left side, it will be $-\sqrt{9-2\sqrt{3}}$.

$$\int_{-\sqrt{9-2\sqrt{3}}}^3{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}y + 9 - \sqrt{3}} - y^2 dy$$

Find the value of the integral and that is the two dimensional area of the glass tilted.

To find the volume for a three dimensional version you will have to evaluate an integral of the area of a circle from zero to the liquid level.

$$f_r(x) = \sqrt{x}$$
$$\int_0^{9 - \sqrt{3}} \pi f_r(x)^2 dx$$

$$\int_0^{9 - \sqrt{3}} \pi x \ dx$$
$$ \pi [\frac{x^2}{2} ]^{9 - \sqrt{3}}_0 $$

$$ \pi * \frac{(9-\sqrt{3})^2}{2} $$
$$=~ 82.974...$$

Comment: This integral don't gives the Volume? I get ca 26.6 (u^3).  I know the volume of the full glass is ca 127.2 (u^3). Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Is the glass three dimensional or two?

Comment: Also, is 127.2 the volume of the full glass tilted?

Comment: The glass is 3-D. Yes at question two.

Comment: @JanA.Haaland, what is $u$?

Comment: @JanA.Haaland What is ca?

Comment: @Jeremy: ca is [_circa_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circa), i.e. approximately.

Comment: $V$ and $V adjusted$ do not match up with your number 127.2.